# No WiFi or Bluetooth on 22.04 Fresh Install on ROG Strix G17 (2022)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04, bluetooth

I was previously using Pop!_OS 22.04 before WiFi, bluetooth, graphics were becoming unstable. I decided to clean install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and now both WiFi and Bluetooth are not working at all. From the `lspci` command, the network device is a MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7922. I chose to install Ubuntu with proprietary drivers.

Laptop Specs:

- 140W 6GB RTX 3060
- Ryzen 6900HX
- 16 GB DDR5 RAM
- 1 TB SSD

Edit:
`nmcli device` output:

```
enp3s0 ethernet unavailable --
enx82045fad6f1d ethernet unavailable --
lo loopback unmanaged --
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I used the command: ``` sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service``` it showed the status as: inactive(dead). I restarted the service and reenabled the service. Still showing inactive (dead). The event mesage shown is: "Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped. "

Comment: Just saw your updated comment. So the solution for my problem is to install the latest kernel?

Comment: Ok. I find it strange that a 2022 machine won't work now with the latest ubuntu LTS. Wifi and bluetooth were working fine for a while on Pop!OS 22.04 LTS. It had a 6.X kernel version while the kernel version on my machine is 5.19

Comment: How would I go about installing the HWE kernel without both wifi, phone USB internet or even bluetooth? I don't have access to etherent. USB drives are working though and I have a mac

Comment: The issue magically fixed itself when I booted into the machine today. I swear I had restarted the machine multiple times before.